# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

My package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "api-auth",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "start-dev": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "build": "npm install --only=dev"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v12.6.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "node-gyp": "^3.8.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Heroku output, it build okay but then it shows this:

```
2020-11-30T17:32:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-30T17:32:25.385955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-30T17:32:27.462352+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-30T17:32:27.462366+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-auth@0.0.0 start /app
2020-11-30T17:32:27.462366+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2020-11-30T17:32:27.462366+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998108+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998157+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998157+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998158+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998159+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/User'
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998160+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998161+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/auth.js
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998161+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998161+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/bin/www
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998163+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998163+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/auth.js:9:14)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998167+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998167+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998167+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998168+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998168+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:14:14)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998170+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12) {
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998170+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998171+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/routes/auth.js', '/app/app.js', '/app/bin/www' ]
2020-11-30T17:32:27.998171+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-11-30T17:32:28.008736+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-11-30T17:32:28.008952+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-11-30T17:32:28.009802+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! api-auth@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2020-11-30T17:32:28.009951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-11-30T17:32:28.010125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-11-30T17:32:28.010259+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the api-auth@0.0.0 start script.
2020-11-30T17:32:28.010391+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-11-30T17:32:28.014982+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-30T17:32:28.015107+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-11-30T17:32:28.015194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-30T17_32_28_011Z-debug.log
2020-11-30T17:32:28.065317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-30T17:32:28.091892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I read this heroku's official page too https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys but for me is not working: I read that I have to put all the dependencies inside `dependencies`, and not in `devDependencies`, so I did that but nothing happens, the error still there.

I tried to delete node_modules and npm i later and is still making the same mistake.

I read too about using a heroku CLI but didnt work for me. I am using github because is easier for me.

Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the path to your module `../models/User` in `/app/routes/auth.js`?

Comment: yes, I have: 
const User = require('../models/User'), and is ok.

And it didnt make any errors when is in localhost

Answer (score 0):

It was a Windows's problem. Windows doesnt differenciate between upper and lower case like Linux. So when I tried to upload my code, it breaks. I write everything in lower case and it works.